# Feats involving Rampage

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

Besides the Charging Rampage feat (D&D 4e PHB2), are there any other feats involving Rampage (Barbarian class feature)?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) the only other ones I found are [Ruthless Rampage](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2707) (Dragon 384 p40) and [Thaneborn Fury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2884) (Dragon 386 p51). (Both links require a DDI account to view)